# Unit Sphere: defining set of points inside its boundary?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I'm trying to create a set of all the points inside the boundary of the unit sphere.  I tried to solve an inequality below, however my solutions do not appear correct.

Definitions:

$$
\theta(n,r,\vec x_o) = \{\vec x :\lVert (\vec x - \vec x_0)\rVert < r \land \vec x \in R^n\} = \{\vec x :\lVert \vec {x_0x}\rVert < r \land \vec x \in R^n\}
$$
$$
\Delta_{\iota\upsilon\iota\upsilon\alpha}(\vec x, \vec x_0) = \lVert \vec x - \vec x_0 \rVert
$$
$$ \lVert \vec x \rVert =\sqrt{\vec x \cdot \vec x}
$$
$$
\cdot(\vec x,\vec y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i y_i
$$
Solving for the interior points of the unit sphere:
$$
\theta(1, 1, 0) = \{|v_1| : \sqrt{v_1^2} < 1 \land \vec v \in R \}
$$

Solving the inequality
$$
v_1 < 1 \land v_1 > -1
$$
but since $\sqrt x$ is a partial inverse to positive values $v_1 < 1$.

**Question** is this solution correct?

Comment: No.  $(x-x_0) \cdot (x-x_0)$ is a nonnegative real number.  (Try it -- it's the sum of nonnegative real numbers.)  The (real) square root function only gives nonnegative results.  So $\sqrt{1} = 1$.  It is never $-1$.

Comment: Then you write $\vec{x} < 1$.  What does that mean?  $\vec{x}$ is not a number.

Comment: In evaluating $\theta(1,1,0)$, you write $\dots < \sqrt{1}$.  Why?  The formula for $\theta$ does not have you take the square root of $r$,

Comment: You might be happier with $\theta(n,r,\vec{x}_0) = \{x \in \Bbb{R}^n : (\vec{x} - \vec{x}_0) \cdot (\vec{x} - \vec{x}_0) < r^2\}$.

Comment: Thanks, I updated.  These comments helped

Comment: The inequalities at the end are still unintelligible.  I can guess from context what you mean when you write "$\vec{x}^2$", but that notation is nonstandard.  Suppose $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ with the $x_i$ real numbers.  Then $\sqrt{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{x}} = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}$.  So your inequality is $x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 < 1$.  Neither $x$ nor $\vec{x}$ appear intelligibly in an inequality.

Comment: @EricTowers I fixed the notation to use a subscript for the vector element.  I also corrected the variable names at the end.  I think that fixes this?

Comment: Umm...  No.  I very much think you need to talk ... at length ... with an instructor about what vectors are, what components of vectors are, and how to use vectors and their components in inequalities.

Comment: @EricTowers I think you're referring to my use of $\vec v$ and $\vec v_1$.  For the later, I was referring to a component of a vector and corrected it, $\vec v$ and $(v_1, ..., v_n)$.  I believe this resolves the issues?

Comment: No.  $\vec{v} \in R^n$ has $n$ components, but you only write one and you only use one in the inequalities you write.

Comment: @EricTowers $\sum_{i=1}^n$ where $n=1$ means only the first component $v_1$ is in the summation.

Comment: $$\text{"}\theta(1, 1, 0) = \{v_1 : \sqrt{v_1^2} < 1 \land \vec v \in R^n \} \text{"}$$ has "$\vec{v} \in R^n$", so $\vec{v}$ has $n$ components, not $1$.  Nowhere have you indicated restriction to $n = 1$, the one-dimensional case.

Comment: @EricTowers I fixed what I think you mentioned as an error. The argument was not substituted for $n$ before, now it is: $
\theta(1, 1, 0) = \{v_1 : \sqrt{v_1^2} < 1 \land \vec v \in R \}$

Comment: In this notation, the open ball $\theta(1, 1, 0)$ is indeed the open interval $(-1, 1)$ sitting in the real line. The remark at the end about the square root seems awry, however. If it matters, for all real $v_{1}$ we have $\sqrt{v_{1}^{2}} = |v_{1}|$, not $v_{1}$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, for $\sqrt {{v_1}^2} = | v_1 |$, doesn't this excluded half of the sphere which are the negative values of $v_1$?

Comment: The formula $\sqrt {{v_1}^2} = \lvert v_1\rvert$ works perfectly well for negative values of $v_1.$ For example, $\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \lvert -1\rvert.$ What does **not** work for negative $v_1$ is if you neglect to take the absolute value on the right-hand side.